# How to pair a Boxanne Bluetooth speaker

Tags: macos, bluetooth, speakers

I was given a [Boxanne](http://www.technomarketinginc.com/?portfolio=boxanne-bluetooth-speaker) bluetooth speaker as a present and have been trying to pair it with my Mac but have so far been unable to.

I just get a message saying:

> Couldn't connect to the device

Is there another way to do this? I'm running 10.12.6 Sierra.

[image]

Comment: Can it be discovered by other Bluetooth devices? Perhaps you should [contact TechnoMarketing](http://www.technomarketinginc.com/contact-2/).

Answer (score 1):

No - there isn’t another way to pair.

I would keep notes on what steps you see when you click Pair.

Does it ask for a passcode? If so, do you enter 0000 or something else?

Can you unpair other devices and re-pair them. Sometimes if there’s a lot of bluetooth devices or a microwave oven or lots of WiFi right where you are, you could get interference.

You can control for that by shutting off all other transmitters - all bluetooth, all WiFi including the router and access points and trying to pair just that mac and just that device. Then you restart both devices - full power down, wait 15 to 30 seconds and power up and repeat.

At that point, if the Mac can’t pair with anything - seek Apple service. If that device can’t pair and others can, seek vendor support.